# DISM command error. Failing to Apply Drivers during SCCM OSD

Tags: deployment, dism, sccm

I am using a SCCM 2012 task sequence to deploy Windows 7 for Dell Precision T5810. Using the "Apply Driver" step in WinPE (64bit): with WMI filtering for model filtering to install a driver package.

Currently failing to apply drivers - I'm not sure where to go from the DISM logs attached; note it fails after successfully applying some drivers. All other computer models apply drivers successfully in other task sequence steps.

- short smsts.log @ http://pastebin.com/VDFDwEUy

  - Note the: "Failed to provision driver. Code 0x80004005" with return     from "Dism failed with return code -2147467259"
- full DISM log @ http://pastebin.com/x3b4gp3v

  - Note the: DISM.EXE: DISM Unattend Manager processed the command line
    but failed. HRESULT=80004005

I think the DISM log lines are relevant:

```
CBS    Failed to load offline schema.dat hive from '\\?\C:\Windows\system32 \smi\store\Machine\schema.dat' into registry key '{bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/Windows/system32/smi/store/Machine/schema.dat'. [HRESULT = 0x80070020 - ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION]
CBS    Failed to unload offline registry: {bf1a281b-ad7b-4476-ac95-f47682990ce7}C:/Users/default/ntuser.dat, the client may still need it open. [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED]
CBS    Failed to load offline store from boot directory: '\\?\C:\' and windows directory: '\\?\C:\Windows\' [HRESULT = 0x80070020 - ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION]
CBS    Failed to initialize store parameters with boot drive: C:\ and windows directory: C:\Windows [HRESULT = 0x80070020 - ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION]
```

Any thoughts? I have found info about 32bit WinPE registry compression, however I am using 64bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure you have got the latest driver package from dell. You can download the drivers [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/7554.precision-t5810-windows-7-driver-pack).

Is your OS image a captured one or an original one? Similar issue occurred as yours [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/f/4448/t/19544668), when built another captured image and used it in the task sequence, it started working. So if you are using a captured image, just test to use a clean image to see if the issue still exists.

Comment: After updating the package it was still failing so I pulled out drivers and added one by one - it was the Intel NVMe driver causeing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday. Because it's to do with DISM, and the TS worked  fine for one machine and not for an identical twin, nad having read through countless number of blogs not finding an answer I thought the problem may hav something to do with the state of the hard disk. So instead of a quick format I did a full format of the HD and created C: drive on the whole of the HD I was applying the OSD to.

That has worked so far. Four out of 4. So all I do is when it comes to put the TS password, I press F8, use diskpart, clean the disk, create and active partition, do a full foramt and finally assign letter C to it.

This has worked for me at least.